Запятая в выражении всё как должно быть; перечисление с "всё"
Мать прикладывала все усилия, чтобы у ребенка была крыша над головой, одежда, еда – всё как должно быть.

Нужна ли запятая перед "как должно быть"?
Нужно ли тире перед "всё", так как это перечисление, или допускается запятая, так как "всё" тоже часть перечисляемого?


Правильно:
Мать прикладывала все усилия, чтобы у ребенка была крыша над головой, одежда, еда – всё как должнО быть.
Пояснение

Тире ставится перед обобщающим слово всё после однородного ряда.

Розенталь,  § 15
 6. Если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами 
 предложения, то перед ним ставится тире: Вся наигранная 
 весёлость, самообладание, сдержанность — всё покинуло Титка 
 в этот момент (Ш.);


Сочетания "всё как должно быть", "все как надо" — синонимы, запятая перед КАК не ставится. Это тема устойчивых оборотов с подчинительными союзами, которые имеют значение одного слова, в данном случае: всё как должно быть — это все правильно.

Сравнить: Всё так, как должно быть. Запятая ставится.
Примечание. При различении придаточных предложений и устойчивых оборотов постановка запятой зависит также от структуры предложения. В частности, в заданном предложении с однородным рядом и обобщающим словом пауза перед союзом КАК нежелательна.
